# Localização de um caractere em python

Tags: python, string

Adaptei um programa em Python que resolve labirintos, e estou melhorando ele, mas tive problemas com o caminho mínimo (Até dei um estudada em Grafos), consegui entender tudo. Mas estou com problema em achar a posição(x,y) do objetivo. Tentei usar o index() mas como tem sub-listas não funcionou muito bem.

usei esse padrão para basear o mapa em um plano cartesiano.

```
maze = """\
###########################
#       #             ## ##
# ##### ### # # ######## ##
#     #     ### #     #   #   
# ### # ##### # # ### ### # 
#     #       #     #   # # 
### #### #### ######### # # 
###    #   ##      ## # # # 
# ### ##   ## #### ## #   # 
# ### ## #### ## # ## ### #
#     #    ## ## # ## #   #
### ### ######## # ## ## ##
#             ##         X#
###########################
"""
EMPTY, BLOCK, STEP, END =" ", "*", ".", "X"
UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT = "˄", "˅", "<", ">"

def solve(maze, x, y, move):

    found = False
    if 0 <= x < len(maze[0]) and 0 <= y < len(maze):
        if maze[y][x] == EMPTY:
            maze[y][x] = BLOCK

            if (solve(maze, x+1, y, RIGHT) or solve(maze, x, y+1, DOWN) or
                solve(maze, x-1, y, LEFT) or solve(maze, x, y-1, UP)):
                maze[y][x] = move
                found = True

        elif maze[y][x] == END:

            found = True 

    return found

if __name__ == "__main__":
    maze = [list(line) for line in maze.splitlines()]
    solve(maze, 1, 8, EMPTY)

    for line in maze:      
        print("".join(line))
```

como posso achar a posição de um termo usando esse padrão?

Comment: Acho que vc quer dizer isso: `maze[1][2]` para saber o conteúdo da sublista, e coloque o código inteiro quando puder!

Comment: Ss, mas como eu faço isso com o index? porque preciso saber a posição do (END), no mapa, uso a lista para o eixo y e as sub-lista para x, mas não sei como localizar a variavel. Penso em fazer um loop while, mas to sem ideias.

Comment: Acho que é isso: maze.find(END)

Comment: Será que teria uma outra forma que retornasse a posição em números? tipo a posição do END[13][26] (sub-lista 13, na posição 26)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parabéns pela inciativa!

Então vamos lá: 
O jeito mais "fácil de começar e difícil de continuar" de fazer esse tipo de coisa é usar sequências dentro de sequências.

De qualquer forma, você está definindo seu labirinto como uma string multilinha - então é melhor transformar ele numa estrutura de dados como uma lista-dentro-de-listas pra você poder endereçar cada ponto automaticamente. Para isso, podemos fazer os sequintes passos:
quebrar a string com o labirinto todo onde houver uma quebra de linha (caractére \n). Usar cada substring obtida assim "como está", já que uma string é uma sequência.  (A `\n` a mais que você põe logo no inpicio do labirinto evita uma linha vazia no começo do mesmo e é importante):

```
maze = maze.split("\n")
```

Pronto. Agora `maze[1][5]`  vai acessar o sexto caractere na segunda linha. O metodo "split" quebra uma string em uma lista de strings no separador indicado (e omite o separador),e é o suficiente para isso. Tanto listas como strings são sequências - então `maze[n]` vai te recuperar uma linha do labirinto.

Agora, labirintos desse tipo são coisas bem legais para começar a entender Orientação a Objetos em Python.  Basta apenas implementar o método `__getitem__` em uma classe, e o Python pode recuperar elementos de lá com a sintaxe `[ ]`, como se fosse uma sequência nativa - e, se o nosso `__getitem__` suportar indices separados por `,`, que são passados como tuplas, podemos acessar elementos no labirinto como `maze[x, y]` com apenas algumas linhas de código.

Para permitir que o labirinto seja alterável, isso é: você possa inserir novos elementos no mesmo depois de criado, vou usar listas dentro de listas, em vez de strings dentro de listas:

```
class Maze:
   def __init__(self, text_maze):
        self.maze = [[char for char in line]  for line in text_maze.split() if line.strip()]

   def __getitem__(self, index):
        # getitem simples, vai retornar um erro do próprio Python
        # se for acessado um elemento com índice errado
        x, y = index
        return self.maze[y][x]

   def __setitem__(self, index, value):
       x, y = index
       self.maze[y][x] = value

   def __len__(self):
      return len(self.maze) 

   def __repr__(self):
      return "\n".join("".join(char for char in line) for line in self.maze)
```

Agora, vocẽ continuando aí, vai dar mais tarbalho você plotar elementos dentro do labirinto (como um personagem andando, ou mesmo o algoritmo mostrando os caminhos já percorridos) no modo texto, to que usar um 
modo gráfico de verdade e ver o labirinto como bloquinhos coloridos na tela.
O terminal é cheio de pegadinhas - enquanto que funções gráficas são feitas pra isso.

Olha só  -  aproveitando o que eu tinha feito de OOP, eu herdei a classe labirinto, e coloquei o código a mais para o labrinto se desenhar usando o tkinter.

Veja o que dá  para fazer com mais 40 linhas (bem espaçadas) e usando o tkinter - (a referência para o canvas do tkinter está aqui: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html )

```
maze_data = """\
###########################
#       #             ## ##
# ##### ### # # ######## ##
#     #     ### #     #   #
# ### # ##### # # ### ### #
#     #       #     #   # #
### #### #### ######### # #
###    #   ##      ## # # #
# ### ##   ## #### ## #   #
# ### ## #### ## # ## ### #
#     #    ## ## # ## #   #
### ### ######## # ## ## ##
#             ##         X#
###########################
"""

import tkinter

class Maze:
   def __init__(self, text_maze):
        self.maze = [[char for char in line]  for line in text_maze.split("\n") if line.strip()]
        print(self)

   def __getitem__(self, index):
        # getitem simples, vai retornar um erro do próprio Python
        # se for acessado um elemento com índice errado
        x, y = index
        return self.maze[y][x]

   def __setitem__(self, index, value):
       x, y = index
       self.maze[y][x] = value

   def __len__(self):
      return len(self.maze)

   def __repr__(self):
      return "\n".join("".join(char for char in line) for line in self.maze)

   width = property(lambda self: len(self.maze[0]))
   height = property(lambda self: len(self.maze))

BLOCK_SIZE = 24

COLORS = {"#": "#000", " ": "#fff", "X":"#f00"}

class TkinterMaze(Maze):
    def __init__(self, root, text_maze):
        super().__init__(text_maze)
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=self.width * BLOCK_SIZE, height=self.height  * BLOCK_SIZE)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.rectangles = {}
        self.update()

    def clear(self):
        for coordinates, rect_id in self.rectangles.items():
            self.canvas.delete(rect_id)

    def update(self):
        self.clear()
        for (x, y), char in self:
            color = COLORS[char]
            rect_id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                x * BLOCK_SIZE,
                y * BLOCK_SIZE,
                (x + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE,
                (y + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE,
                fill = color,
                width = 0
            )
            self.rectangles[x, y] = rect_id


    def __iter__(self):
        for y, line in enumerate(self.maze):
            for x, char in enumerate(line):
                yield ((x,y), char)


def main():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    maze = TkinterMaze(window, maze_data)
    window.bind("destroy", window.destroy)
    tkinter.mainloop()

main()
```

Olhando um pouco amis a documentação do tkinter, você poderá  usar o "bind" de eventos para receber teclas pessionadas e fazer o personagem percorrer o labirinto.  (Uma implementação melhor será com o persongaem numa classe separada, com uma referência ao labirinto - ai usando o "getitem" ele pode saber para onde pode onde não pode ir. Ele pode compartilhar o ".canvas" do labirinto para se desenhar na mesma tela, ou o labrinto pode incorporar uma outra "camada" para desenhar os objetos que não são parede)

Comment: Genial !! Muito obrigado msm!! Tava tentando achar uma forma a uma semana kkk,classes não são o meu forte, Vou dar uma estudada a mais em POO pra passa pro modo grafico. Mas por enquanto acho que consigo plotar os elementos no labirinto kk. Explicação limpa e objetiva! obg cara!!

Comment: Depois de ver esse código, vou ter que aprender a usar esse tkinter kkk, ficou muito foda !!

Comment: eu na verdade sempre faço coisas do tipo desse labirinto com pygame - mas além de necessitar de uma instalçao a parte, o pygame é meio "cru" : o programador tem que fazer tudo, e se precisar usar texto no programa, tem basicamente que re-inventar a roda.

O tkinter vem com o python e tem tudo pronto, mas por algum motivo as pessoas não estudam ele.

Comment: Já ainda to começando nessa parte de labirinto, Essa questão msm de acha a localização no (END), é pra tentar aplica o A* no código pra fazer o caminho mínimo, mais isso exige mais do que eu pensava. já ouvi muito sobre tkinter, mas ainda não uso porque estou usando o Blender game engine, facilita algumas coisas pra mim que ainda não tenho muita experiencia.

Comment: O blender game engine é uma boa pra isso também. O que seria ruim só seria tentar ficar no modo texto.

Comment: aí complica, mas tento manter o equilíbrio entre o modo texto e o resto todo, pra não ficar muito dependente.

Comment: O porblema é que no modo texto você não tem algo consistente, multi-plataforma, para imprimir cores, ou imprimir um carctére numa posição específica. pra fazer isso dá mais trabalho que usar uma biblitoeca para fazer de modo gráfico. Imprmir um labirinto embaixo do outro cada vez que o personagem uma posição é bem feio.
Mas no modo texto no Unix (MacOS/Linux), existe o módulo "curses" - dê uma olhada.

Comment: Não sabia disso, vou dar uma olhada sim.